# Will the downtime from upgrading my AWS RDS instance affect my celery message queue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, django-celery, rds

Currently I have an AWS RDS instance that is running at 85% CPU and I would like to upgrade it to an XL. The only problem is that my celery queue currently has 60,000 tasks (Hence the 85% cpu usage). My thought is that the downtime from the instance will fail many of my tasks if I decide to upgrade. Is there any way I can pause? Will it fail only a few tasks?

Comment: For a multi-AZ RDS instance total downtime will be roughly 5-20 seconds. Celery should automatically put failed tasks back into the queue.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you! This is a terrible question, but is there anyway I could pick and choose which tasks to skip in my queue at the moment.

Comment: If you are really concerned, you can stop the worker processes. However, if your software architecture can't tolerate any kind of unexpected downtime, it's bound to fail.